# Start Activity for result in a Broadcast Receiver?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

I have managed to get an Activity to start from my `onReceive()` methdod, but I really need to do a `startActivityForResult();`.

Is there any way I could do this?

On a side note, how would I make my app become a 'camera' app, as in it would appear when an app started the intent to take a picture?

Answer (score 4):

The important thing to know about broadcast receivers is that you should not add long running processes in it, because after something like 5 seconds your app will crash.

The best thing to do in your case is to intent to other Activity from your broadcast receiver, and from that activity use `startActivityForResult()`, get the picture and continue from there...

Comment: But how would I return the image uri to the app that requested it? That is what I was going to do, until I realized that I needed to pass data back.

Comment: Why you need to use this broadcast receiver?
what are you'r filters for broadcast?
you want to build application that will run instade of the camera?

Comment: Yes, and no. I want to build an app that will run as if it was a camera app, but it actually allows the user to select an app from their gallery instead of taking a new picture.

Comment: you want to create an app that allow user pick one photo from already taken pictures. is this understanding correct?

Comment: Is there a more elegant solution here than daisy chaining activities together? I think I would rather not make an activity for the sole purpose of starting another activity for result.

Answer (score 2):

`startActivityForResult` can only be called from an `Activity` since it is defined in the `Activity` class and require instance of activity.

You can only call `startAcivity()` from broadcast receiver since in `onRecieve()` you only have access to generic `context` object and it does not have `startActivityForResult` method defined in the class..

Comment: Which I discovered, so how can I get some data back when I call an activity from the receiver?

Comment: can you please explain your use case.. broadcast receiver are not meant to be used like that.. from official java doc **A BroadcastReceiver object is only valid for the duration of the call to onReceive(Context, Intent). Once your code returns from this function, the system considers the object to be finished and no longer active.**